# java cli application distribution

Tags: java, jar, command-line-interface, software-distribution, binaries

If I were to distribute my CLI application, that consists of `jar`, which manifest declares a `main` class, which takes command line arguments and produces some output like a normal CLI application would, and a `.bat` and `.sh` scripts, that ease the launch of the `.jar`, relieving the user of writing `-java -jar yadda yadda`, just resorting to `myapp somecommand -flag` type of stuff.

How would I package such application to distribute it to users?

I don't think native binary files like Windows `.exe` file is what I need, because I want the application to remain CLI only.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not a simple ZIP file containing the jar and the script ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/index.html